# AHK If key pressed do this

Tags: autohotkey

I'm currently making a script that is supposed to activate if a key is pressed. Anyone mind helping me out with this?

Code:

```
PressTheKey:
Send, {T}
MouseClick, X1
Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a [hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm), like so:

```
A::
Send, {T}
MouseClick, X1
Return
```

In this example, the <kbd>A</kbd> key will trigger the script.  You can change that to any key you like.

Comment: You don't want to wrap `T` in `{}`, that's only supposed to be done to escape characters that have a special meaning in a [send command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm). In worst cases it could even result in unexpected behavior with the command. More about this from the documentation. Also, [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) is generally preferred over normal `Send`.

Comment: @0x464e There is nothing wrong with wrapping *individual* keys in braces and it will never lead to unexpected behavior. Indeed, you would want to if you needed to send multiples of the same key (`Send, {S 30}` from the help file).

Comment: @0x464e With regard to `SendInput`, note that the template file includes `SendMode Input` at the start. It may be worth recommending this instead of constantly using `SendInput` in place of `Send`.

Comment: @EJE What you said about it never leading in unexpected behavior is just simply not true. Maybe read the documentation. And I don't know what template file you're referring to. I'm not seeing any such file anywhere.

Comment: From the autohotkey docs:

[v1.1.27+]: Enclosing a plain ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) in braces forces it to be sent as the corresponding virtual keycode, even if the character does not exist on the current keyboard layout. In other words, `Send a` produces the letter "a" while `Send {a}` may or may not produce "a", depending on the keyboard layout.

So it really depends on what the OP wants to do.  If they want to push the literal key, this is the way to go.  If they are more concerned about typing an "a" in text, then they should remove the braces.

Comment: And the template EJE is referring to is the template file that is created when you create a new script by doing Right Click > New > AutoHotkey Script, and I can confirm it does have a `SendMode Input` line at the top, which affects all subsequent calls to `Send`.  It's also worth mentioning that there are legitimate reasons to use other send modes.

Comment: Yeah, I never recommend `SendMode`, because you might want to the other modes as well. And it's not like typing `SendInput` take any longer than typing `Send`. You probably (or least should) have autocomplete where ever you type code.